# What would cause a browser to submit a POST request from an HREF?

Tags: spring, http, post

We have a Java Spring application where one of the URLs is mapped as a `GET`,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/advanced-search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String advancedSearchHome(Model model) {
   //...
}
```

All references to this URL are from an `HREF`, link (`<a href=..>`) or JS `location.href`:

1)

```
<a href="<spring:url value="/advanced-search?token=${searchToken}"/>"
```

2. 

```
<button onclick="location.href='../idp/advanced-search/'" ...
```

In some very rare instances, the browser sends an incorrect `POST` request to `/advanced-search` (99% of the time this doesn't happen). What could possibly explain the following rare occurrence? Could it be something like an Incognito mode, or some other explanation?

```
10.243.114.139 - - [28/Jul/2022:17:23:51 -0400] "POST /idp/advanced-search/ HTTP/1.1" 200 13357
10.243.114.139 - - [28/Jul/2022:17:24:01 -0400] "GET /idp/advanced-search/ HTTP/1.1" 200 170552
```

Comment: Equally curious is that your service appears to be responding with a 200 from the POST call.  Have you narrowed it down to which of the two links causes this or do they both trigger this behavior?

Comment: It's not entirely clear which link caused it. The log shows this POST at the specified time and we also got an error notification about it.